# How to set http status code in AWS apigateway for error responses

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, integration

AWS API Gateway returns always 200 for all requests(success/error) in postman.
How to change the status code in AWS API gateway if the response if failure.
My response will be as following

```
"ResponseHeader": {
    "ResponseId": "c4ddf534-4634-45d8-af1a-bad89ae63066",
    "RefRequestId": "dd2338e3-11ab-42cc-9c5a-4d88babbab91",
    "Status": "Failure",
    "Message": "Response Failed",
    "ResponseContext": {
        "ResponseTime": {
```